# C++ How to protect against invalid input?

Tags: c++, validation, input

In my program, I want users to choose between two choices. Simply, 1 or 2. I have written the program to where it will protect against an invalid numeric value such as 3 or 28, but I cannot protect against alphabetical input.

Code is as follows:

```
int whileInt = 0;
int choiceOne_One = 0;
while(whileInt == 0)
{
    cin >> choiceOne_One;

    if(choiceOne_One != 1 && choiceOne_One != 2)
    {
        cout << "Woah! That wasn't an option! Try Again.\n";
    }
    else if(choiceOne_One == 1)
    {
        whileInt++;
        cout << "\nYou have died. Be more careful.\n";
    }
    else if(choiceOne_One == 2)
    {
        whileInt++;
        cout << "\nYou have survived the alien invasion due to your cunning sense of "
            "safety.\nCongratulations.\n";
    }
}
```

My brain still works in Java, please help me figure this out. It will definitely be appreciated.

Comment: Try reading a whole line at a time using getline().

Comment: That did work, thanks. I switched  the variable type from int to string and used your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading a `std::string` with `std::getline`, then simply compare the string with "1" or "2". Otherwise, you can just read the whole line with `std::getline`, then use `std::stoi` (C++11) to transform the read string into an integer. The result of [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) tells you whether the transformation was successful or not (i.e., whether the string represented an integer). If successful, then you can simply compare the integer with `1` or `2`. If not successful, then an `std::invalid_argument` or `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown.

First case (with `std::string` comparison):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    if (input != "1" && input != "2")
        std::cout << "Invalid input!";
}
```

Second case (using `std::stoi`):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    int n = std::stoi(input); // throws exception if cannot convert to int
    if (n != 1 && n != 2)
        std::cout << "Invalid input!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the method I ended up using. But when using std::stoi, how can I catch that it is valid or not  and relay that to the user and allow them to re-input?

Comment: @HoustonDavis you can use a `try/catch` block together with a loop and a `bool`-ean flag.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char input;
    cin>>input;
    switch(input)
    {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            cout<<"valid input"<<endl;
        break;

        default : 
            cout<<"Invalid input"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can define a case for all your valid inputs, leave the rest to default.
Integers from 0-9 have their ASCII values from 48-57 respectively.
This solution wont be helpful if you have
    . input>9 or input<0
    . input such as 1abc

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it might be a bit more efficient. I'll be sure to keep that method in mind.

Comment: There's never an excuse for writing `48`..`57` instead of `'0'`..`'9'`.

Comment: @hvd : I am comparing the ASCII values of integers because my data type for input is "char". Using 0-9 might result in acceptance of invalid inputs.

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey `'0'` is not `0`

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey again the issue is that if you input `1abc`, it will read `1` and think it read correctly, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

#### Might be a bit late but my favorite way to do and this is what i use :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>    
//T is for our variable and lambdaFunc will be our lambda function or
//function pointer
template<typename T, typename lambdaFunc>
auto secureEntry(T& variable, LambdaFunc lFunc, std::string errorMessage) //can ommit error message
{
    while(!(std::cin(variable)) && !lFunc(variable)){
        std::cout << errorMessage << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(), '\n');
    }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int mynumber = {0};
    std::string errorMessage = "Please use a number bigger than 0 and lower than 5"
    secureEntry(myNumber, [](int& mynumber) -> bool{
        return mynumber > 0 && mynumber < 5;    
    }, errorMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this also

```
    int whileInt=0;
    int choiceOne_One = 0;
    while(whileInt == 0)
    {
    cin >> choiceOne_One;

    if (choiceOne_One == 1 || choiceOne_One == 2){
             if (choiceOne_One == 1){   
                 whileInt++;
                 cout << "\nYou have died. Be more careful.\n";
             }
             else {
                 whileInt++;
                 cout << "\nYou have survived the alien invasion due to your cunning sense of "
                  "safety.\nCongratulations.\n";
             }
    }
    else {
         cout << "Woah! That wasn't an option! Try Again.\n";        
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think OP wants something like `1abc` to be invalid. In your code, `1` is read from the stream

Answer (score 0):

If you change the program so that `cin` puts a User's answer to a std::string, then you could do tests on the string value.

If the string's length() was more than 1, it cannot be '1' or '2'

There are additional tests you can do, like `std::isalpha(int ch)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

      std::string value;

      std::cin >> value;

      std::cout << "Value is " << value << "\n";

      std::cout << "length of value is " << value.length() << "\n";

      char ch;

      ch = value.at(0);

      if(std::isalpha(ch)) std::cout << "You did not enter a number" << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

robert@debian:/tmp$ g++ -Wall test.cpp

robert@debian:/tmp$ ./a.out 
123
Value is 123
length of value is 3

robert@debian:/tmp$ ./a.out 
abc
Value is abc
length of value is 3
You did not enter a number